# Munin master cannot trace data from munin node

Tags: munin, debian-jessie

I'm new to Munin, I followed the tutorial on digital ocean to install munin master on a debian, and then a munin-node on another server also under debian 8.9.
Munin master is working perfectly, from master I nmaped the munin node server on the 4949 port, there is a response, so I think it's not a network or firewall problem.
With the command

```
systemctl status munin-node
```

The output says it is up.
But still I have no link on the web interface of munin master to munin node.
This is the output of the munin master (munin-update.log)

```
2018/01/13 10:05:11 [INFO] Reaping Munin::Master::UpdateWorker<MuninNode;MuninNode>.  Exit value/signal: 18/0
2018/01/13 10:05:13 [ERROR] In RRD: Error updating /var/lib/munin/MuninMaster/MuninMaster-http_loadtime-loadtime-g.rrd: /var/lib/munin/MuninMaster/MuninMaster-http_loadtime-loadtime-g.rrd: found extra data on update argument:
2018/01/13 10:05:13 [INFO]: Munin-update finished for node MuninMaster;MuninMaster (11.67 sec)
2018/01/13 10:05:23 [INFO] Remaining workers: MuninNode;MuninNode
2018/01/13 10:05:23 [INFO] Reaping Munin::Master::UpdateWorker<MuninMaster;MuninMaster>.  Exit value/signal: 0/0
2018/01/13 10:05:23 [INFO] No old data available for failed worker MuninNode;MuninNode.  This node will disappear from the html web page hierarchy
2018/01/13 10:05:23 [INFO]: Munin-update finished (21.85 sec)
```

How can I check if munin node is sending data to munin master?

Also I noticed there is a MuninMaster (it's the name I gave to the master) folder under /var/lib/munin, but no such thing as MuninNode (the name I gave to munin node in the munin.conf file)
Thank you for your help

Comment: Have you set up the "host tree" in munin.conf @ master? should be here: /etc/munin/munin.conf

Comment: I supposed yes. I have this [MuninNode]
    address 5.111.111.111
    use_node_name yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nodes do not send data to the master.  The master pulls data from the client.  You need to add the node to the `/etc/munin/munin.com`, and restart the master.  The master will then pull data from the node.  Normally, the master will be one of the nodes that is monitored.

You can telnet to port 4949 on the node from the master to test.  The protocol is text based.

I documented my experience [Monitoring with Munin](https://www.systemajik.com/blog/monitoring-with-munin/).

Comment: When telnet to the munin-node IP, i've got Name or service not known. Can't I use nmap instead? btw I allowed port 4949 in FirewallD, seems ok now